# Is There a Script, Export, or Stored Procedure to Convert a SQL Table to MediaWiki Table Format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

SSMS T-SQL 2012

Hello,

If I have a table such as the following:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (A varchar(5),B varchar(5),C varchar(5))

INSERT @table VALUES
('r1c1','r1c2','r1c3'),
('r2c1','r2c2','r2c3'),
('r3c1','r3c2','r3c3');

select *
FROM @table
```

Is there a way to convert the table to a mediawiki table such as the following?

```
|-
| r1c1  
| r1c2  
| r1c3
|-
| r2c1  
| r2c2  
| r2c3
|-
| r3c1  
| r3c2  
| r3c3
|-
```

I couldn't find any published articles on how to do this.  Perhaps a Stored Procedure or other script exists?  I didn't see any export format in SSMS 2012 that would perform this.  It seems like a lot of work to use brute force T-SQL with a PIVOT to perform this, but I could be wrong.

Thank you for the time reviewing my inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tt.val
from @table t cross apply
     ( values ('-'), (a), (b), (c) ) tt (val);
```

Comment: Well that was fast.  how about inserting the breaks?  I think I could handle the prefixing.

Comment: @DataMan31. . . I think you should not do such thing with `SQL` that could be easily do with presentation layer.

Comment: Ahh yes, adding the ('-') column handles the breaks well.  Thank you for the fast response.  I can run with this!